# Hadoop: Using a job's output file as a second job's input file (FileNotFound)

Tags: java, file, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to run a mapreduce program using the output file from a job as the input file to a second job.  I have this current code:

```
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
        job.setJarByClass(BookAnalyzer.class);
        job.setJobName("N-Gram Extraction");

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
        FileStatus[] status_list = fs.listStatus(new Path(args[0]));
        if (status_list != null) {
            for (FileStatus status : status_list) {
                FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, status.getPath());
            }
        }
        Path nGramOutput = new Path(args[1]);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, nGramOutput);

        job.setMapperClass(BookNGramMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(BookNGramReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        
        if(job.waitForCompletion(true)) {
            
            Configuration conf2 = new Configuration();
            Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2);
            job2.setJarByClass(BookAnalyzer.class);
            job2.setJobName("Term-frequency");

            FileSystem fs2 = FileSystem.get(conf2);
            FileStatus[] status_list2 = fs2.listStatus(nGramOutput);
            if (status_list2 != null) {
                for (FileStatus status : status_list2) {
                    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, status.getPath());
                }
            }
            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job2, new Path(args[2]));

            job2.setMapperClass(TermFreqMapper.class);
            job2.setReducerClass(TermFreqReducer.class);

            job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
            
            System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
        }
```

I get an error saying Input path (nGramOutput) does not exist, but if my first job executes correctly, which it does, that file in args[1] should be created.

So,

> args[0] = initial file
>
> args[1] = output file from first job, and input file for second job
>
> args[2] = output file from second job

Any advice would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: For each job you are trying to get new configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do [**chaining jobs**](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/chaining-jobs-in-hadoop-mapreduce.html).

Try this

```
Your Class {
  private static final String OUTPUT_PATH;
}
main(){
 Configuration conf = new Configuration();
 FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
 Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);
 job.setJarByClass(BookAnalyzer.class);
 job.setJobName("N-Gram Extraction");
 Path nGramOutput = new Path(OUTPUT_PATH);

 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job,args[0]);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, nGramOutput);

 job.setMapperClass(BookNGramMapper.class);
 job.setReducerClass(BookNGramReducer.class);

 job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

 job.waitForCompletion(true);

 Configuration conf2 = getConf();
 Job job2 = Job.getInstance(conf2);
 job2.setJarByClass(BookAnalyzer.class);
 job2.setJobName("Term-frequency");

 FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job2, nGramOutput);
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job,new Path(args[1]));

 job2.setMapperClass(TermFreqMapper.class);
 job2.setReducerClass(TermFreqReducer.class);

 job2.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 job2.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

 System.exit(job2.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
 }
```

**The paths used are**

```
args[0] : Input path
nGramOutput : Intermediate output form job1, which acts as input to job2
args[1] : Final output path
```

**So your command to run your job will be**

```
hadoop jar myjar.jar args[0] args[1]
```

You dont have to give 3 arguments

```
args[0],args[1],args[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should setup dependency between jobs.

If i remember the API :

job2.addDependingJobs(job1);